# simple jquery ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

heres my ajax:

```
$('#savecustomer').click(function() {   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax-newcustomer.php",
        data: ({ name : $('#ncname').val(), address : $('#ncaddress').val(), postcode : $('#ncpostcode').val(), dob : $('#ncdob').val(), mobile : $('#ncmobile').val(), email : $('#ncemail').val() }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert('sc success');
            if (data == 'error')
            {
                $('#ncsuccess').attr('display', 'none');    
                $('#ncerror').attr('display', 'block');
            }
            else
            {               
                $('#ncname').val('Name');
                $('#ncaddress').val('Address');
                $('#ncpostcode').val('Postcode');
                $('#ncdob').val('Date of Birth');
                $('#ncmobile').val('Mobile Number');
                $('#ncemail').val('Email Address'); 

                $('#ncerror').attr('display', 'none');  

                $('#ncsuccess').html(data);                 
                $('#ncsuccess').attr('display', 'block');                   
            }
        }
    });
});
```

its not showing me the alert at all. meaning it isn't succeeding....i'm guessing its something to do with the data: format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use the `error` callback of the `ajax` method to help you see what is happening:

```
error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
}
```

This way you can see if it's a **404** (so the page path is wrong), a **500** (some server-side error) etc.

Answer (score 2):

the data should be an object literal in your case without the ()

```
 ...
 data: { 
        name : $('#ncname').val(),
        address : $('#ncaddress').val(),
        postcode : $('#ncpostcode').val(),
        dob : $('#ncdob').val(),
        mobile : $('#ncmobile').val(),
        email : $('#ncemail').val()
},
 ...
```

in addition - i would gather all the values before the ajax call in the following way:

```
var ncname = $('#ncname').val();
```

this will let you verify the valuse in a more convenient way in firebug/chrome dev tools
oh.. almost forgot - check fiddler or other tool to see if a request was even sent to the server to see if it rejected it

Answer (score 1):

Remove the brackets ( and ) around the data.

Answer (score 0):

add error handler and see what error is returned:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax-newcustomer.php",
        data: (...),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            ...
        },
        error: function(err){  ... check err here ...}
    });
```

Also, no brackets around data